# Microphone picking up sounds from phone's speakers producing feedback

Tags: android, audio, microphone, audio-processing

I set up something that processes live surrounding audio (picked up by the microphone) and is replayed almost in real time from the phone's speakers.

However, this is producing feedback as the phone's microphone picks up the sounds that are just produced by the phone's speakers.

Are there any ways to prevent this feedback / echoing?

Comment: Hi @Justin Ma, I am also facing the same problem. Have you found the solution? If yes, then please share it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`AcousticEchoCanceler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AcousticEchoCanceler).

Another approach might be more speaker/mic isolation, for example by plugging in headphones, instead of using the speaker.